# Windows8 x64 usb can't be recognized issue

Tags: windows, windows-8, usb, drivers

I am having problem with my usb port. I am basically trying to attach my mobile via USB cable but it always says device not recognized as in below image:

[image]

Universal Serial Bus controllers:

[image]

The device used to work fine previously. As can be seen in image above, when I insert the usb cable, it goes under `Other Devices > Unknown Device`

### What I've tried

- Tried putting usb cable in other ports - same result
- Tried uninstalling all drivers under Universal Serial Bus controllers, unplugged everything and restarted
- Tried Microsoft Fix it (it said my windows version isn't supported :( )
- Tried unplugging laptop battery and all cables and restarted after half hour
- Tried updating drivers from dell's support site
- Tried Windows 8 refresh feature
- Tried disabling Allow this computer to turn of device to save power
- Tried disabling turning off device via Advanced Power settings
- Tried updating drivers via device manager automatically update option but it said it is latest driver already
- Tried connecting other usb cables with same result

### Other Details

- When I put anything else in those usb ports, it works for example mouse
- Same mobile and usb cable works on others' computer
- If I put friend's mobile usb cable in these ports, it works fine
- Device manager says power required for usb devices is `0MA`

### Possible Hint

One day I booted my pc and it said there is no battery and when re-started it worked fine ever since then I have no same no-battery warning message. However, this usb problem I *think* has come up since then.

Had anyone had similar problem, should I change something in Bios ? is there kind of Microsoft Fixit utility for Windows 8 as well ? Overall, how do I resolve/get rid of usb device not recognized issue ?

FYI: I am using Dell Inspiron 15R 5521 laptop with Windows 8 64bit.

P.S: Please don't suggest solutions I've already tried listed above.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

If your USB device is detected properly in another PC then the problem will be with your motherboard's USB controller. Otherwise your USB device is broken.

Comment: Thanks but how could usb device be broken, as I said If i put anything else on these ports, it works, even others' usb mobile cable works fine

Comment: Sorry. I did not read the question completely before answering. It is your mobile.I thought it to be pen drive. In this case It can be problem with your mobile's data cable. Or it may be because of driver malfunction. Check if your mobile is detected in another PC. As other devices works, there is nothing wrong with your port. Either faulty cable or driver is the culprit.

Comment: Also try connecting with another cable.

Comment: I also mentioned in question same mobile usb cable works fine on others' pc :)

Comment: Tried connecting other cables as well same result :(

Comment: Did you try reinstalling windows?

Comment: Nope I haven't, I tried using windows 8's refresh feature though. Re-installing windows seems to be the last option but posted question here to possibly avoid it